# how to delete particular item from firebase storage map?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

[image: Data Structure]

How to delete item a particular item from 'Image' map in flutter. my structure is shown in the attached image.

Comment: How do you know what a "particular" item is?  What information do you have to work with that you would use to delete the item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Image` is an array, if you want to delete an item from the array, then do the following:

```
void deleteItem() async{
var firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
Firestore.instance.collection("stories").document(firebaseUser.uid).updateData({
  "images" : FieldValue.arrayRemove([imageURL])
}).then((_) {
  print("success!");
});
}
```

Assuming the document id is the current `userId`, then you can use `arrayRemove` to remove an item from the array.